# Как правильно писать: "event-мероприятие", "ивент-мероприятие" или "эвент-мероприятие"?

Tags: стилистика, переводы

Как писать правильно: event-мероприятие, ивент-мероприятие, эвент-мероприятие?

Comment: А что такое "event-мероприятие, ивент-мероприятие, эвент-мероприятие", не подскажите? Чем оно отличается от обычных встречи, события, мероприятия?

Answer (score 5):

Согласно словарю английского языка event - это событие. Соответственно event-мероприятие - это событие-мероприятие, то есть "масло масляное". Зачем ненужные заимствования? Просто оставьте слово мероприятие или событие.

Answer (score 1):

Это слово ещё не зафиксировано нормативными словарями, поэтому говорить о правильности или неправильности нельзя. Написание пока не устоявшееся, но в практике письма чаще используется вариант ***э**вент-мероприятие.* Так что если уж вы не хотите использовать русский аналог (что было бы разумнее всего), то можно рекомендовать написание с буквой **э**.

Comment: Утверждение "в практике письма чаще используется вариант эвент-мероприятие" не соответствует истине. 
По запросу //"эвент-мероприятие" -"event-мероприятие"// в Гугле — 117 результатов, а по запросу //"ивент-мероприятие" -"event-мероприятие"// — 294 результата.

Comment: Когда я производил такой поиск (для верности повторил только что), статистика была иной: Google выдал 2620 результатов для первого запроса и 2980 – для второго. Я, однако, счёл её нерепрезентативной: разницу в 12 %, как вы понимаете, никак нельзя считать сколько-нибудь надёжным основанием для предпочтения одного варианта другому. По-видимому, единственный надёжный источник, на который мы можем здесь положиться, – ответ Справочного бюро Грамоты.ру на вопрос № 237473: http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_318442
Что думаете об этом? А заодно и о различающихся ответах Гугла? Я их объяснить не могу.

Comment: Не смотрите на начальные числа: очень много повторов. Перейдите  на последнюю страницу и посмотрите текст внизу — "Чтобы показать наиболее значимые результаты, мы опустили некоторые, очень похожие на //ЧИСЛО// уже показанных." Сейчас по запросу

"эвент-мероприятие" -"event-мероприятие"

42 результата, а по запросу 

"ивент-мероприятие" -"event-мероприятие"

294 результата. Вероятно, и сотрудник Справочного бюро Грамоты.ру не стад переходить на последнюю страницу. Сейчас по запросу

"эвент" -"event"

447 результатов, а по запросу 

"ивент" -"event"

774 результата.

Answer (score 0):

Ивент-мероприятие.